Simplify the following using logical equivalence, and prove equivalence: ~(~p ∧ q) ∧ (p ∨ q) ≡ p
Simplify the following using logical equivalence, and prove equivalence:$\newcommand{\lsim}{\mathord{\sim}}$
$$\lsim((\lsim p) \wedge q) \wedge (p \vee q) \equiv  p$$
Just to specify this is the example 2.1.14 from the book "Discrete Mathematics with Applications". In the book, looking at the solution, I was stumped how step 3 happened after step 2:
Step 2: $(p \vee \lsim q) \wedge (p \vee q)$
Step 3: $(p \vee (\lsim q \wedge q))$
I used truth values and found that
$$\lsim((\lsim p) \wedge q) \wedge (p \vee q) \equiv  p$$
is true but I am not able to prove it using only logical equivalence.

$\newcommand{\lsim}{\mathord{\sim}}$We are working with the expression
$$\lsim((\lsim p) \wedge q) \wedge (p \vee q)$$
The first step uses $\lsim(A\wedge B)\equiv\lsim A\vee\lsim B$ and $\lsim(\lsim A)\equiv A$ and concludes that the given expression becomes
$$(p \vee \lsim q) \wedge (p \vee q)$$
Now, the book uses the identity
$$(A\vee B)\wedge(A\vee C)\equiv A\vee(B\wedge C)$$
This identity with $A=p$, $B=q$ and $C=\lsim q$ gives that the given expression further becomes
$$p\vee(\lsim q\wedge q)$$
Finally, it is easy to show that $\lsim q\wedge q\equiv\bot$ (here, $\bot$ means false). Thus, the statement becomes
$$p\vee(\lsim q\wedge q)\equiv p\vee\bot\equiv p$$
where $p\vee\bot\equiv p$ is straightforward.
Hope this helps. :)

I forgot to read the theorem 2.1.1 in the book properly, as you mentioned it now that property is indeed present in the book.

That is called distributive law.
$$p \vee (q\wedge r) \equiv (p\vee q) \wedge (p\vee r).$$
